# How to alter input field style and position inside a form

Tags: html, css, hugo

I'm currently getting into HTML and CSS a bit but am having trouble understanding how to make this form behave how I would like. The goal is to get the first three fields to maintain their current behavior, but have the Subject and Message fields be appropriately sized and on their own lines.

I have tried adding `div`s, changing the display and position settings on the class, and adding separate classes to try and target the fields I want to behave differently.

```css
.optin {
    background-color: #F7F9FA;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 40px 70px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px 0px rgba(61, 65, 84, 0.15); }
    .optin__title {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 32px; }
    .optin__form {
        display: flex; }
    .optin__form-group--active > label {
        top: -20px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #FA6262; }
    .optin .form-group {
        flex: 1 0 0;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .optin__label {
        position: absolute;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 15px;
        top: 12px;
        left: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
    .optin__input {
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D9ED; }
        .optin__input:focus {
            background-color: transparent; }
        .optin__input:focus ~ label {
            top: -20px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #FA6262; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .optin {
            padding: 30px; }
            .optin__form {
                display: block; } }
```

```html
          <div class="optin">
            <h3 class="optin__title">{{ .Site.Params.home.formtitle }}</h3>
            <form class="optin__form">
              <div class="optin__form-group form-group">                    
                <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-name" required>
                <label for="optin-name" class="optin__label">{{ .Site.Params.home.formname }}</label>
                <span class="input-underline"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-email" required>
                <label for="optin-email" class="optin__label">{{ .Site.Params.home.formemail }}</label>
                <span class="input-underline"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
                <label for="optin-company" class="optin__label">{{ .Site.Params.home.formcompany }}</label>
                <span class="input-underline"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
                <label for="optin-subject" class="optin__label">{{ .Site.Params.home.formsubject }}</label>
                <span class="input-underline"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
                 <label for="optin-message" class="optin__label">{{ .Site.Params.home.formsubject }}</label>
                <span class="input-underline"></span>
              </div>

              <button class="optin__btn btn btn--md btn--color btn--button">{{ .Site.Params.home.formsubmit }}</button>                 
            </form>
          </div>
```

Changing `.optin__form` in CSS to `display: relative` gives me the desired behavior but unfortunately applies it to all fields.

Comment: Using a class selector (.) will change every HTML element that has been given that class _ To select specific elements use an id (#) and create CSS separately for that element _ To create CSS styles for some elements but not all _ create a new class and add it only to the elements you want to target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options, all of which are fairly easy. Here is one [which I think from your description is what you're loking for]:

- Put the first three items in their own div (I called it `optin__form-row`). This will be the name/email/company fields on the top row of the form.
- Set the `display` to `flex` on that. Everything will still look the same atm, so:
- Remove `display: flex;` from the `.optin__form` class - you don't need the while form to flex, you now just want the elements to sit above each other.
- add `display:block` and `width:100%` to `.optin-input`. This will push the input elements to full allowed width.

You'll still need to sort the spacing/paddings/margins a bit, but that should give you the layout I think you're looking for.

```css
.optin {
  background-color: #f7f9fa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 40px 70px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px 0px rgba(61, 65, 84, 0.15);
}
.optin__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.optin__form-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
/* NOTE I changed this from .optin .form-group
 * to `optin__form-group & added relative positioning: */
.optin__form-group {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.optin__form-group--active > label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fa6262;
}
.optin__label {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.optin__input {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d9ed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.optin__input:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.optin__input:focus ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fa6262;
}
/* NOTE I'm just commenting this out for the purposes of
 * the snippet:

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .optin {
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .optin__form {
    display: block;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="optin">
  <h3 class="optin__title">Form Title</h3>
  <form class="optin__form">
    <div class="optin__form-row">
    <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-name" required>
      <label for="optin-name" class="optin__label">Name</label>
      <span class="input-underline"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-email" required>
      <label for="optin-email" class="optin__label">Email</label>
      <span class="input-underline"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
      <label for="optin-company" class="optin__label">Company</label>
      <span class="input-underline"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
      <label for="optin-subject" class="optin__label">Subject</label>
      <span class="input-underline"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="optin__form-group form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-input optin__input" id="optin-company">
      <label for="optin-message" class="optin__label">Subject</label>
      <span class="input-underline"></span>
    </div>

    <button class="optin__btn btn btn--md btn--color btn--button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great! I think the only thing not working perfectly is the mobile display (top 3 fields squish together instead of transitioning into a stack as they did previously) but I think that's another issue entirely.

Thanks a bunch! I'll poke around and try to get a better handle on why what I was trying wasn't working but now that I've got a working solution to dig into I can hopefully make some more progress on my journey :)

Comment: Yup, with that I'd probably look at just applying a media query to the group & switch to `display: block` on mobile (or set `flex-direction: column`). Glad this was useful though!

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I'd probably have spent quite a while before even getting close enough to google media query lol. Appreciate all the help, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add and modify your styles as give below

```
.optin .form-group {
    position: relative;
}
.optin__title {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.optin__input:focus ~ label {
    top: -45px;
}
```